# Detecting pinch-zoom in firefox on android

Tags: javascript, android, firefox

In the other Android browsers (Chrome and the default-one) pinch-zoom fires window.resize
- Not so in Firefox : (
So how do I detect it (surely it can't be impossible) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: I inserted a (hidden) div with width:100%.
And a function that regularly monitors this div's width.
- When the width **in pixels** changes, zoom has changed
(or orientation or screen size.. whatever): call myResize().
Demo: http://krydster.dk - Crossword puzzle game (danish).